# Python quiz issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have to design a basic quiz and it's fairly simple at the moment.
Essentially, I have 10 questions and I have incorporated a scoring system and I have managed to create a percentage system.

Here is my code:

```
# Quiz Game

import random
import sys



score = 0 # -> initial score
print("Your score is currently " + str(score))

qa = [('In which Australian state was the highest temperature of 53 deg C recorded? ', 'Queensland'),
      ('What animal is featured on the 2c coin? ', 'Frilled neck lizard'),
      ('What Australian company is the largest surfwear manufacturer? ' , 'Quicksilver'),
      ('How many ships were in the First Fleet? ', '11'),
      ('In what year was decimal currency introduced in Australia? ', '1966'),
      ('What was Sir Donald Bradman’s batting average? ', '99.94'),
      ('How much of Australia is classified as desert A) 8% B) 16% C) 25% D) 35% ', 'D'),
      ('On which Australian decimal banknote did a portrait of Henry Lawson appear? A) $5 B) $10 C) $20 D) $50 E) $100 ','B'),
      ('True or False, Bathurst is held at Mt. Panome? ', 'False'),
      ("Who was Australia's former F1 driver to Daniel Ricciardo? ", 'Mark Webber')]

random.shuffle(qa)

for q,a in qa:
  user_answer = input(q)
  if user_answer.lower() == a.lower():
# -> determining if the answer is correct or not
    print("Correct!")
    score = score+1
    print('Your score is currently ' + str(score)) # -> scoring system
    print ("Your Percentage is: ")
    print((score/10)*100) # -> this is the percentage calculation
  if score==2:
    print('Congratualtions, you have beaten the quiz')


  else:
    print("Incorrect!")
    print("The answer is " + a)
```

My current issue is I am unsure as to how I can do the following:
1) If the user gets 7 correct answers, quit early and display a winner message.
2) If the user gets 3 incorrect answers, quit early and display a loser message.

How can I do this? I am fairly new to python and haven't used it in a while so I'm a little rusty. I need to keep this platform but any additions you guys think of would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 simply because I love trivia.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pseudo code to get you started. You basically have the right idea.

```
score = 0
incorrect = 0
for q,a in qa:
    user_answer = input(q)
    if user_answer.lower() == a.lower():
        score += 1
    else:
        incorrect += 1

    if score == 7:
        print('some message')
        break
    if incorrect == 3:
        print('some message')
        break
```

Comment: I tried that @Pushkin however it didn't work, I got a syntax error because of the breaks.

Comment: Does it not print out the specific line of code that's causing the error?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? It works for me. If it's Python 2, you might want to change `input(q)` to `raw_input(q)`.

Comment: Version 3.4.1 When using your method It doesn't even run?

Comment: Did you copy and paste it exactly? I had a "..." in my code. That could have caused an issue. Edited my answer.

Comment: This is my code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7T0xtNhpIRZZGpRODJfYW43ME0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JUnit_2 print is a function in python 3.x that it it should be opened and closed with `()`

Comment: @VigneshKalai Ahh I see. Thanks for the help - I'm not very familiar with Python 3.x

Comment: @JUnit_2 Also make sure you have consistent indentation.

Comment: @JUnit_2 happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a while loop, which checks for either of your conditions:

```
import random
import sys

# qa = [...]

random.shuffle(qa)

correct = 0
incorrect = 0

while correct != 3 or incorrect != 7:
    for q,a in qa:
       print('Your current score is: {}'.format(correct))
       print('Your percentage is: {}'.format((correct/10)*100))
       user_answer = input(q)
       if user_answer.lower() == a.lower():
           correct +=1
           print('Correct!')
       else:
           incorrect += 1
           print('Incorrect! The correct answer is {}'.format(a))

if correct == 3:
   print('You won!')
if incorrect == 7:
   print('You lose!')

# End of code
```

Comment: Where does this go in my actual code, when I try to adapt this into my code it doesn't work. @Burhan Khalid